# Should new researchers volunteer to review conference papers?

Tags: peer-review, conference, service-activities

I am a graduate student pursuing a master's degree in Information Systems, and I have never published a paper before.

I am planning to submit a paper to a conference, and the conference specifically asks if those submitting papers are willing to also act as reviewers.

I am willing to review, but I'm not clear if it would be appropriate for me to volunteer, given the stage of my academic journey.

In the general case, are these kinds of voluntary review opportunities typically appropriate for students? Or are these limited to those who already possess advanced degrees?

Comment: Can you tag a field? It is important when discussing conferences that have "papers," as I gather the norms are much different in math/CS and related fields than in others.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Field is Information Systems, edited to add. No tag exists for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are a bit early in the journey, but if you have research experience in a topic and let the editor of the journal know your background then you could ask. Likewise for the conference. Send a note to the conference or program chair about your interest.

Doctoral students toward the end of their studies are more likely candidates, along with those with doctorates, but you could make the offer and see what happens.

However, don't stray from what you really know and don't spend so much effort at it that you lose track of your own studies. That is, by far, the more important task.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be fine. The volume of submissions in many conferences overwhelmed the peer review capacity and it's now not unusual for organizers to ask all paper authors to review for the conference.

It may be intimidating to write your first paper review, but it's okay, trust your guts. The success of peer review system relies on every reviewer trying their best to judge a work independently. No one should tell you that you're not qualified, as long as you feel so. A good source to learn how to write peer reviews is https://openreview.net (especially the ICLR conference). Also here is the CVPR reviewer's guideline if it helps https://cvpr2022.thecvf.com/reviewer-guidelines.